# Refresh variable in ListView builder after looking into Firestore in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-listview, stream-builder

I have a Listview.builder() in StreamBuilder. In the Listview builder I need to get a data for every item in Firestore, and after I show the data. But because the look into the database is a Future action, I'll need the await method for waiting the data and show after.

Here is my code, I created in 2 different class.

First class :

```
StreamBuilder getFriends() {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(AuthFunc().currentUser!.uid)
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        log("${snapshot.data["Contact"]}");
        List list = snapshot.data["Contact"];
        friends = list;
        return ListviewSharedWidget(
            friends: friends, year: widget.year, idDay: widget.idDay);
      }
      return Container();
    },
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SizedBox(
    height: 450,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 400,
          child: getFriends(),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Second class :

```
@override
void initState() {
  year = widget.year;
  idDay = widget.idDay;
  friends = widget.friends;
  _getText();
  super.initState();
}

Future<void> _getText() async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Users")
      .doc(AuthFunc().currentUser!.uid)
      .get()
      .then((value) {
    textEditingController.text = value["Answers"]["$year"]["$idDay"]["text"];
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: friends.length + 1,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      String name = ""; // This variable causing problem
      TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(friends[index - 1])
          .get()
          .then(
        (value) {
          name = value["Name"]; // Here I update the variable
          controller.text = value["Answers"]["$year"]["$idDay"]["text"];
        },
      );
      return Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFieldSharedWidget(
              controller: controller, // But this variable is well updated and the text 
                                      // is displayed
              name: name, // But when I use here, the variable is still empty
              currentUser: false,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If each item requires you to load another document from the database asynchronously, consider wrapping that load operation in a `FutureBuilder`. It may look a bit weird at first, but keep in mind that `FutureBuilder` is just another widget like any other - so it typically works fine even when you have a list of them.

So something like:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: friends.length + 1,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return FutureBuilder(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(friends[index - 1])
          .get(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("ERRor: ${snapshot.error}");
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(snapshot.data!.child("Name").value);
          }
          return CircularLoadingIndicator();
        },
      );
    }
  );
}
```

*Note: I didn't test the above code, so please try to fix syntax and minor problems on your own.*

---

A common way to prevent having to load all these individual documents is to duplicate the data that you need in the original document. For example, if you don't just store the UID of each friend, but also their name, you can display the entire friend list without having to load all the separate friend's documents.

This sort of data duplication is incredibly common when dealing with NoSQL databases. If you are new to this domain, I recommend checking out [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video).